# NVIDIA DEBUG MANAGER FOR ANDROID NDK ECLIPSE PLUGIN

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk, nvidia

Can anyone tell me where can i get.

NVDebugMgrForAndroidNDK

its is an "NVIDIA DEBUG MANAGER FOR ANDROID NDK ECLIPSE PLUGIN"

Thanks

Comment: The first google result for "NVDebugMgrForAndroidNDK" is a PDF on the NVidia site which contains installation instructions including a download link.. now you try.

Comment: i tried that but if you check that link. it doesnt lead to the plugin file

Comment: if you got it please add the link in the comments below.

Answer (score 3):

It's available as part of Nvidia's [Tegra Android Development Pack](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack).

Answer (score 0):

I install 4.0r2 version for but didn't see NVDebugMgrForAndroidNDK