# Where to find NVidia Debug Manager for Android/Eclipse NDK Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk, nvidia

This was answered a year or so ago here:
[NVIDIA DEBUG MANAGER FOR ANDROID NDK ECLIPSE PLUGIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305560/nvidia-debug-manager-for-android-ndk-eclipse-plugin)

I am stuck at Help/Install New Software. I can't find the archive that is supposed to contain the NVDebugMgr plugin.

When I downloaded Nvidia's Tegra Android Development Pack it isn't in there. The only thing in the archive is tadp-2.0-r5-osx.app.

I am trying to install according to these instructions: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/NVDebugMgrForAndroidNDK-InstallGuide_20110228.pdf.  I can't find NVDebugMgrForAndroidNDK_900.zip anywhere and it's not in the tadp described in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Download Tegra Android Development Pack from: https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack

Then, while installing the pack, choose custom installation from installation options and select Nvidia Debug Manager for Android to install in Select Components screen. You will see the required zip file in your installation directory after its download is finished.